# three.js import fails in Create React App

Tags: three.js, create-react-app

I have three.js installed in my Create React App project as:

`"three": "^0.115.0",`

When I try to import it in component by doing:

`import * as THREE from "three";` then I get (abridged):

```
TypeError: attribute.onUploadCallback is not a function
createBuffer
node_modules/three/build/three.module.js:14471
  14468 | gl.bindBuffer( bufferType, buffer );
  14469 | gl.bufferData( bufferType, array, usage );
  14470 | 
> 14471 | attribute.onUploadCallback();
        | ^  14472 | 
  14473 | var type = 5126;
```

If I create a file such as:

```
import * as THREE from "three";

window.THREE = THREE;

export default window.THREE;
```

then I am able to successfully import from there.

I have no idea why I need to add it to `window` for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The error actually had to do with a related library that uses three.js called AMI.js.